# Why Eclipse displayed the error " <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true" whereas I set it to false?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web, war

I just created a simple Maven project, i want it without web.xml.
Eclipse display this error while I set it to true (see pom.xml) :

[image]

```
<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Does anybody has an idea of what is involved here ?

Comment: Does the message show up in the Problems view? The Type shown there would provide a clue for where the message came from. Isn't the default `false` on this version any way?

Comment: Yes, and also in the pom.xml as shown in the picture.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " The Type shown there would provide a clue for where the message came from". Sorry I'm french ^^

Comment: In https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/view_problem.png, you see that there's a column named "Type." It can help figure out where the message comes from. This sounds like what ever is generating the message has a bug in it.